# Override parent tables border properties

Tags: html, css

My html is like:

```
<html class="t1">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><table class="t2 grid"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</html>
```

In my CSS I have:

```css
.t1
{
 display: table;
 width: auto; /* 885*/
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.t1 td
{
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.t2
{
 display: table;
 width: auto; /* 885*/
 border-collapse: collapse;

}
.t2 td
{
 border-collapse: collapse;

}

.t2 grid
{
            border-top:1px solid #eeeeee !important;
            border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee !important;
            border-left: none !important;
            border-right: none !important;
}
.t2 grid td
{
            border-top:1px solid #eeeeee !important;
            border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee !important;
            border-left: none !important;
            border-right: none !important;
}
```

Sorry I can't post my actual CSS or HTML, but that is the idea of it.

Now for some reason the parent tables grid lines are showing up on the right/left of each row in the inner table.

I'm looking at chrome and I can see the computed styles, and the parents styles are still in effect.

How can I fix this?

The problem is, the inner table now has a very strong outer border because the style (i think) is being applied 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you're naming your CSS styles. It should be `.t2.grid td` not `.t2 grid td`.

Comment: Your markup is also wrong, you need to open the table tag, I think you meant `<table>` instead of `<html>`

Comment: Also, I think @Ryan Brodie meant `.t2 td, .grid td{...}`; in the way you put it, it is "a td element with parent grid with parent t2", I'm I wrong?

Comment: It depends on what the user is intending by his original markup. If he want's the style just to apply to table cells (td) with the classes t2 & grid, then the style tag should be `.t2.grid`.

Comment: Oh, `.class1.class2 != .class1 .class2` second case is what I say?, my bad then, I didn't know that! I'm a newbie aswell.

Comment: @Roger No it's not, not to worry :)

Comment: so is that what you always do, when chaining classes you don't leave a blank, but with selectors you leave a blank?  man how can I not know this yet!

Comment: @user1361315 Yes. It's because spaces in CSS denote new element tags, not combinations of Classes or ID's. E.g. div.ryan table.brodie

Comment: (By new element tag, I meant as in a new **nested** element)